# ubuntu device security fails

Tags: 23.04

ubuntu privacy/device security gives me this error message. I am attaching the screenshot and device security report. Please tell me if its something to worry about or not. If yes how do I solve it?
[hardware checks failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEb9e.png)

```
Device Security Report
======================

Report details
  Date generated:                                  2023-05-05 15:41:56
  fwupd version:                                   1.8.12

System details
  Hardware model:                                  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. H410M H V3
  Processor:                                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-10100 CPU @ 3.60GHz
  OS:                                              Ubuntu 23.04
  Security level:                                  HSI:0! (v1.8.12)

HSI-1 Tests
  Intel Management Engine Version:               ! Fail (Not Valid)
  UEFI Platform Key:                               Pass (Valid)
  TPM v2.0:                                        Pass (Found)
  Firmware BIOS Region:                          ! Fail (Not Locked)
  Firmware Write Protection Lock:                ! Fail (Not Enabled)
  Platform Debugging:                            ! Fail (Enabled)
  Intel Management Engine Manufacturing Mode:      Pass (Locked)
  UEFI Secure Boot:                                Pass (Enabled)
  Firmware Write Protection:                       Pass (Not Enabled)
  Intel Management Engine Override:                Pass (Locked)
  TPM Platform Configuration:                      Pass (Valid)

HSI-2 Tests
  Intel BootGuard Fuse:                          ! Fail (Not Valid)
  Intel BootGuard Verified Boot:                 ! Fail (Not Valid)
  Intel BootGuard ACM Protected:                 ! Fail (Not Valid)
  Intel BootGuard:                                 Pass (Enabled)
  IOMMU Protection:                              ! Fail (Not Found)
  TPM Reconstruction:                              Pass (Valid)
  Platform Debugging:                              Pass (Locked)

HSI-3 Tests
  Suspend To RAM:                                ! Fail (Enabled)
  Intel BootGuard Error Policy:                  ! Fail (Not Valid)
  Pre-boot DMA Protection:                       ! Fail (Not Valid)
  Intel CET:                                     ! Fail (Not Supported)
  Suspend To Idle:                               ! Fail (Not Enabled)

HSI-4 Tests
  Encrypted RAM:                                 ! Fail (Not Supported)
  Intel SMAP:                                      Pass (Enabled)

Runtime Tests
  Firmware Updater Verification:                   Pass (Not Tainted)
  Linux Swap:                                    ! Fail (Not Encrypted)
  Linux Kernel Lockdown:                           Pass (Enabled)
  Linux Kernel Verification:                       Pass (Not Tainted)

Host security events
  2023-05-05 13:32:18   Linux Kernel Lockdown        Pass (Not Enabled → Enabled)
  2023-05-05 13:32:18   UEFI Secure Boot             Pass (Not Enabled → Enabled)

For information on the contents of this report, see https://fwupd.github.io/hsi.html
```

Comment: At the bottom of your report: "*For information on the contents of this report, see https://fwupd.github.io/hsi.html*" which seems to answer this question.

Comment: there are just details but no solutions